# vbscript use regex to rename files recursively

Tags: regex, recursion, vbscript, rename

I am trying to write a vbscript to recursively rename any files in a folder.
My final plan will be to copy the folder to a zip file, but it fails if the files have any characters apart from

e.g (a-z) or (0-9) or "_", " ".

For example, if the file has characters other than English in the file name, it will not allow me to copy the file to the zip. I have looked at various websites and could have an answer in batch as well.

I am quite new to regex, having started learning about it yesterday.

The error I am getting is "File already Exists".

My script:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppend  = 8
Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE

scriptdir = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objStartFolder = scriptdir & "\Fragments"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

objRegEx.Global = True

objRegEx.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z_0-9-\n\r]"

For Each objFile in colFiles

If regEx.test(objFile.Name) = true Then

FirstlevelNewFileName = objRegEx.Replace(objFile.Name, "_")

objFSO.MoveFile objFile, FirstlevelNewFileName

End If
Next

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)


Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)

For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles

        NewFileName = objRegEx.Replace(objFile.Name, "_")

objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, NewFileName

    Next

    ShowSubFolders Subfolder

Next

End Sub
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. If there are illegal characters in the filename, Windows won't allow the file to be created in the first place, so your regex should never do anything. So you're never assigning anything to `FirstlevelNewFileName` and never trying to move the file (the `if` never gets entered).

Comment: @KenWhite For example, if I use lets say, chinese characters or something similar in the file name, it lets me name the file that, but it doesn't let me copy the file to the zip file without renaming it.

Comment: Then you still have a logic flaw. Let's say `@` represents any one of the hundreds of thousand *Chinese or other "invalid" characters*, and you have the file 'ABC@.txt` (where `@` can be any one of those hundreds of thousands of characters, remember?) and `ABC@.txt` (where `@` is a different one of those hundreds of thousands of characters), and you're replacing all of those characters with the same `_`. You now have two files with identical names, even though they didn't start off that way.

Comment: You are right, but I am not sure currently how to solve that problem and `_` seemed like the best option. (I didn't _really_ want to add numbers/letters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code have got issues with the `Movefile` statements(when you are trying to rename files). You are providing only the file name as the Destination parameter. You should provide full path there. I have made changes as shown below.

NOTE: I did not change any of the Logic.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppend  = 8
Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE

scriptdir = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objStartFolder = scriptdir & "\Fragments"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

Set objRegEx = new Regexp

objRegEx.Global = True

objRegEx.Pattern = "[^\w.]"     'looks for non-word characters and also not .(for the extension)

For Each objFile in colFiles

    If objRegEx.test(objFile.Name) = true Then                  'Changed this. You had only used the variable RegEx here instead of objRegEx

        FirstlevelNewFileName = objRegEx.Replace(objFile.Name, "_")

        objFile.Move objStartFolder&"\"&FirstlevelNewFileName    'Provided the full file path here. Used the File Object itself

EndIf
Next

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)


Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)

For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)

    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

    For Each objFile in colFiles

        NewFileName = objRegEx.Replace(objFile.Name, "_")

        objFile.Move Subfolder.Path&"\"&NewFileName       'passed the full path here again

    Next

    ShowSubFolders Subfolder

Next

End Sub
```